# Why pytube and pytube3 doesnt work at all after installation

Tags: python, pytube

Writing a script to download a YouTube video I face the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\migue\Desktop\PythonScripts\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pytube import YouTube
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'
PS C:\Users\migue\Desktop\PythonScripts>
```

I already installed pytube and pytube3 on my cmd and on my project folder but I still get the error.

What could it be? My code is very very simple and I don't know how I did wrong.

```
from pytube import YouTube
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO8hi9JEzNg'
YouTube(url).streams.first().download()
```

Comment: How did you *"install pytube and pytube3 on your cmd"*?

Comment: pip install pytube

Comment: Are you in a virtual environment or using the system `site-packages`? Also, do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: I dont have any venv. I am running Python 3.8.5. And I created a new folder on Desktop to archive the python file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, which I solved by installing the package from its GitHub repo:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube
```

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved like you. `youtube-dl` is working well but `pytube` not working well.